# Is it grammatically correct to say that my hairs are long?

Tags: grammar

From high school, my English teacher always emphasized on English words which are read the same in their singular and plural form. One of them being hair, yet most people still say hairs for hair. Please help

Answer (score 0):

No it's not,  the correct way is to say " My hair is long"
Hairs can be correct it all depends on the context clues of the sentence like "There's dog hairs on the couch"

Comment: Welcome to SE. While there is nothing wrong with answering your own question, you need to explain how context matters, rather than just say it's important. How do you use context to determine which word is right? But in any case, this question has been answered before.

Comment: It's more subtle than that even. My hair (on my head is long) and my nose hairs are long too.